# Inserting document into MongoDB "can't extract geo keys" with Multi Polygon

Tags: json, mongodb, geospatial, geo

It's been awhile since I've used MongoDB for GEO related things so excuse me if this mistake is simple

I have a document I'm trying to insert (See [PasteBin Link](https://pastebin.com/Fm3VmZBM)) but keep getting "*can't extract geo keys*"

In my collection, I have this index: `zone_data.features.geometry` type: `2dsphere`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue

Some of that longitude coordinates were out of range. (min: -180, max: 180)